# Integers $m$ and $n$ such that $9|(m + 2n + 1)$ and $9|(5m + n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I'm attempting to disprove this statement by contradiction and just want to check if what I've done makes any sense at all:

"There exists a pair of integers $m$ and $n$ such that $9|(m + 2n + 1)$ and $9|(5m + n)$."

Disproof:

For the sake of contradiction, assume there is a pair of integers $m$ and $n$ such that $9|(m+2n+1)$ and $9|(5m+n)$.

From here I was thinking I could do the following:
$$m+2n+1 = 5m+n$$
$$n=4m-1$$

So then, $$m+2(4m-1)+1 = 9m-1$$ and $$5(4m-1)=9m-1$$
As it is not the the case that $9|(9m-1)$, $m$ and $n$ does not exist.

Looking over this, I feel like there is a flaw in my first step. That I can't actually set $m+2n+1$ and $5m+n$ equal to each other. But I also am not sure where to start otherwise. I would appreciate some opinions. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Your last step is not valid either. You argue that $9$ does not divide the right side, but why should it divide the left side ?

Comment: **Hint** $\ 9\mid 5m\!+\!n\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}n \equiv_9 -5m \,\Rightarrow\, m\!+\!\!\underbrace{2\color{#c00}n}_{-10m}\!\!+1 \equiv_9 1$ ($\not\equiv 0)\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $9$ divides $(5m+n)$ and $(m+2n+1)$, then $9$ divides any  number of the form $A(5m+n) + B(m+2n+1)$ (can you see why?). What happens if you set $A=2$ and $B=-1$?

Comment: I suggest that this answer is accepted. Nothing to add. (+1)

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your answer. I understand this concept a lot better now!

Comment: @UnderMathUate. Good.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to deduce $b=c$ from the fact that $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$. For instance $9\mid 18$ and $9\mid 27$.

What you *can* deduce is that there are integers $x,y$ such that
$$
m+2n+1=9x,\quad 5m+n=9y
$$
If you subtract the first equation from twice the second one, in order to eliminate $n$, you get
$$
9m-1=9(2y-x)
$$
Can you now see the contradiction?

Comment: Yeah, I could tell there was faulty logic in that statement but I wasn't sure where to go otherwise. This makes a lot more sense now!